# How to pivot this table in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

I came across this issue when trying to make use of this "active users" table from Microsoft NAV. What I got asked to do is a Dashboard in Power BI or other tool that will allow the company I work for to understand how many users are active on the NAV system at any point in time. I found a DAX formula in Power BI that could do the trick - but it requires the following table transformation:

I am trying to do this in SQL Management Studio:

My SQL Server is Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.

How could I pivot this NAV table below with the following structure knowing that Session ID might repeat further down the line?

```
Session ID  |    Event Datetime       | Event Type
350              2017-07-01 01:00       Logon
350              2017-08-01 02:00       Logoff
351              2017-07-01 02:00       Logon
351              2017-08-01 03:00       Logoff
350              2017-09-01 01:00       Logon
350              2017-09-01 02:00       Logoff
```

The final result would be each Session ID against their Logon and Logoff time (allowing duplicates if Session ID repeats like in this example)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best

Andre

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: What have you tried so far?????  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am using SQL Management Studio v17.3. Any ideas how to solve it horse_with_no_name?

Comment: SQL Management Studio is not a database, rather it is a database client. It works with several Microsoft SQL Server versions, which are you using? The query string ```@@VERSION``` will tell you.

Comment: This is Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is TSQL code and will run on an Azure database. I think this will get you the results you are looking for.

```
DECLARE @ActiveUsersLog AS TABLE
      (
          sessionId     INT
         ,EventDateTime DATETIME
         ,EventType     VARCHAR(50)
      );

INSERT INTO @ActiveUsersLog
     (
         sessionId
        ,EventDateTime
        ,EventType
     )
VALUES
     (350, '2017-07-01 01:00', 'Logon')
    ,(350, '2017-08-01 02:00', 'Logoff')
    ,(351, '2017-07-01 02:00', 'Logon')
    ,(351, '2017-08-01 03:00', 'Logoff')
    ,(350, '2017-09-01 01:00', 'Logon')
    ,(350, '2017-09-01 02:00', 'Logoff');

WITH cte_logon
    AS (
           SELECT aul.sessionId
                 ,aul.EventDateTime
                 ,seq = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY aul.sessionId ORDER BY aul.EventDateTime)
             FROM @ActiveUsersLog AS aul
            WHERE aul.EventType = 'Logon'
       )
    ,cte_logoff
    AS (
           SELECT aul.sessionId
                 ,aul.EventDateTime
                 ,seq = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY aul.sessionId ORDER BY aul.EventDateTime)
             FROM @ActiveUsersLog AS aul
            WHERE aul.EventType = 'Logoff'
       )
SELECT o.sessionId
      ,LogonTime = o.EventDateTime
      ,LogoffTime = f.EventDateTime
  FROM cte_logon AS o
      LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_logoff AS f
          ON o.sessionId = f.sessionId
             AND o.seq = f.seq;
```

If you are only looking for active users then you would add this where clause: (make sure to remove the semicolon at the end of the code above before adding a where clause)

```
where f.EventDateTime is null
```

Comment: Thanks a lot John! Thanks exactly what I was looking for! Now I need to think about how to count the number of users at any given time =)

Comment: You're almost there, replace the last select statement with this:

'SELECT activeUsers = COUNT(*)
  FROM cte_logon AS o
      LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_logoff AS f
          ON o.sessionId = f.sessionId
             AND o.seq = f.seq
 WHERE f.EventDateTime IS NULL;'

Comment: `SELECT activeUsers = COUNT(*)
  FROM cte_logon AS o
      LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_logoff AS f
          ON o.sessionId = f.sessionId
             AND o.seq = f.seq
 WHERE f.EventDateTime IS NULL;`

Comment: Hi John! You are genius! Thanks for this - really helpful! What if we were to have a table with a date column (going from 01/01/2017 all the way to 01/12/2017) against another column with the number of users that were active on that day?  Would that be very complicated? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Not complicated at all. In fact you could use a Tally Table to generate the dates for you instead of building a date table (Having a date table in a database is a great thing but I digress.
Check out this article [http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/] for some inspiration.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the views will not have the indexes, and thus the select query might get significantly slower as the data set grows. I could be wrong, my MSSQL is a little rusty.

Comment: Perfect - thanks both! I have been working on the Concurrent Users code and feel I am nearly there! I will create a new thread with what I got to so far  - any ideas are welcome =)  Thanks a lot

Comment: Link to the next stage of this process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514953/concurrent-users-in-the-system

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the flavour of SQL, I can only give you basic advice.

By performing an inner join with both sides lining to the same table (aliasing appropriately) matching on the `session_id` of both sides, you can then filter `Event Type` on one of the aliased tables to equal `Logon` and `Event Type` on the other aliased table to match `Logoff`.

This method should work on just about any form of SQL I've used, as it's core functionality of SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help SEoF! Now I need to get to the table that will be counting the number of users at any given time =)