# Concurrent users in the system

Tags: azure

This is the second and final stage from the following thread:
[How to pivot this table in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47461399/how-to-pivot-this-table-in-sql/47462147?noredirect=1#comment81911311_47462147)

In summary this is a request from the finance team at this company I currently work for. We are trying to get to this table with the number of concurrent Microsoft NAV users at any given day throughout the year. My first thread (which you can see above) was on transforming or pivoting this raw data as explained below:

Example of original Raw data structure

```
Session ID |   Event Datetime     | Event Type
     1         2017-07-01 00:00      Logon
     1         2017-07-02 01:00      Logoff
     2         2017-07-03 00:00      Logon
     2         2017-07-04 01:00      Logoff
```

On this journey so far we have been able to transform (with the help of you guys) the raw data table above into the following table:

```
Session ID |      LogonTime           |      LogoffTime
    1      |     2017-07-01 00:00     |      2017-07-02 01:00 
    2      |     2017-07-03 00:00     |      2017-07-04 01:00
```

The second and last step now is to build this table with the max number of users that logged on the system per day within this specific date range throughout the year.

I have been playing around with it and got to the code below. I feel I am nearly there - but the final results of max sessions per day don't seem quite right yet to me. The code I got to is the following:

```
  WITH range AS (SELECT cast('2017-07-10'as datetime) AS [start_date]  , cast('2017-12-31'as datetime) AS [end_date])   -- inclusive bounds
, cte AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   [NAV_licenses], range r
   WHERE  [LogonTime]  <= r.[end_date]
   AND    [LogoffTime] >= r.[start_date]
   and [Session ID] =1
   )
, ct AS (
   SELECT log_date, sum(ct) OVER (ORDER BY log_date, ct) AS session_ct
   FROM  (
      SELECT [LogoffTime] AS log_date, -1 AS ct FROM cte
      UNION ALL
      SELECT [LogonTime], 1 FROM cte
      ) sub
   )
SELECT log_date, max(session_ct) AS max_sessions
FROM   ct, range r
WHERE  log_date BETWEEN r.[start_date] AND r.[end_date]  -- crop actual time range
GROUP  BY [log_date]
ORDER  BY [log_date];
```

The output of this query should be the following table:

```
Log_Date        |   Max_Sessions
2017-07-10      |        1
2017-08-10      |        4
2017-09-10      |        6
```

However I am getting multiple results for the same day. Any ideas / suggestions on how to improve this query are more than welcome!

This is Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 by the way.

Thanks a lot,
Andre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a much easier way to get that result:

```
WITH cte_logon
    AS (
           SELECT aul.sessionId
                 ,aul.EventDateTime
                 ,seq = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY aul.sessionId ORDER BY aul.EventDateTime)
             FROM ActiveUsersLog AS aul
            WHERE aul.EventType = 'Logon'
       )
    ,cte_logoff
    AS (
           SELECT aul.sessionId
                 ,aul.EventDateTime
                 ,seq = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY aul.sessionId ORDER BY aul.EventDateTime)
             FROM ActiveUsersLog AS aul
            WHERE aul.EventType = 'Logoff'
       )
SELECT WorkDate = CONVERT(DATE, o.EventDateTime)
    ,SessionCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM cte_logon AS o
      LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_logoff AS f
          ON o.sessionId = f.sessionId
             AND o.seq = f.seq
    GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, o.EventDateTime)
    ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, o.EventDateTime)
```

Here is the result set:

```
WorkDate    SessionCount
2017-11-01  12
2017-11-02  12
2017-11-03  13
2017-11-04  14
2017-11-05  22
2017-11-06  14
2017-11-07  14
2017-11-08  20
2017-11-09  10
2017-11-10  17
2017-11-11  20
2017-11-12  11
2017-11-13  16
2017-11-14  17
2017-11-15  20
2017-11-16  20
2017-11-17  17
2017-11-18  15
2017-11-19  19
2017-11-20  18
2017-11-21  16
2017-11-22  19
2017-11-23  21
2017-11-24  8
2017-11-25  17
2017-11-26  10
2017-11-27  16
2017-11-28  8
2017-11-29  12
2017-11-30  18
2017-12-01  20
2017-12-02  28
2017-12-03  17
2017-12-04  19
2017-12-05  8
2017-12-06  13
2017-12-07  12
2017-12-08  16
2017-12-09  18
2017-12-10  16
2017-12-11  9
2017-12-12  24
2017-12-13  24
2017-12-14  13
2017-12-15  20
2017-12-16  17
2017-12-17  17
2017-12-18  12
2017-12-19  15
2017-12-20  20
2017-12-21  19
2017-12-22  22
2017-12-23  22
2017-12-24  24
2017-12-25  18
2017-12-26  17
2017-12-27  17
2017-12-28  19
2017-12-29  20
2017-12-30  18
```

Comment: I used a MUCH larger data set to test this. I generated 1000 logins and then inserted matching logouts 6 hours later. The data generation script will not fit in an answer post. Let me know if this test data is something you need and I will find a way to get it to you.

Comment: John once again you nailed it! Thanks a lot for that! It would be great to have this test data you used to run this script! The sample data they provided me with doesn't look right to me - I noticed that for some ID sessions the number of logon / logoff are not even and -  due to that - you end up with more logoffs than logons or more logons than logoffs for those Session IDs. In your view I should ask them to provide me a cleaned decent table with an even number of logon / logoff per Session ID or this is probably a bug on the NAV system and I should find a workaround for that issue?

Comment: I support a relatively large Azure app but I am not aware of the NAV system. Can you tell me how to pull this data from a production app? I could use that live data to see if I am getting the same mismatches. That would tell us if your issue is just bad test data or if there is something awry in the platform.

Comment: Use this to create the test dataset:

<https://www.evernote.com/shard/s87/sh/a3eaa4d0-9f33-420a-96fa-8b0db7638600/9d5e51699fa50b93>

Comment: Perfect! I will write to the IT guys now and ask them how to get to this SQL Session ID table with logon and logoffs. As soon as I have any news on this one I will come back to you! How can I reach you btw? Thanks a lot for the dataset - will download and run your script against it!